# Bootstrap: 'selector' option must be specified when initializing tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I get this error in the console when I load my page. It seems to be a fatal error because it's stopping all other JavaScript on the page to not run.

`Uncaught Error: 'selector' option must be specified when initializing tooltip on the window.document object!`

The errors show that it has something to do with a tooltip for bootstrap. Here are my boostrap imports:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/third_party/bootstrap335dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/third_party/bootstrap335dist/css/bootstrap.css">
```

Comment: please post the code

Comment: Pay attention how view file(s) is/are loaded, in what order and be sure jQuery is loaded before bootstrap.js file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap.js throws a selector option error: selector option must be specified when initializing tooltip on the windows.document object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37840492/bootstrap-js-throws-a-selector-option-error-selector-option-must-be-specified-w)